# NAudio - 1.7 - Converting WAV to MP4

Tags: audio, wav, naudio, aac

I am trying to convert a PCM Wav file recorded with the WasapiLoopbackCapture class to an AAC file. The Wav file is 44100, 32bit, 4 channels.

```
using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader("recordedfile.wav"))
{
     MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToAac(reader, "encodedfile.mp4");
}
```

However, i get a COMException from the MediaFoundationReader:
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D5212

What am i doing wrong here and what would be the proper way to convert from PCM WAV to AAC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This probably means you haven't got an AAC encoder (or something is up with the WaveFormat of your recorded WAV file). What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: i will check the AAC encoder, but it's failing in the reader, and not in the Encoding method. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

Answer (score 0):

I battled this problem for a few days before ultimately discovering that you need to install The Microsoft Media Foundation AAC Decoder.

https://superuser.com/questions/819227/how-to-fix-missing-media-foundation-microsoft-aac-audio-decoder-transform-mft-wi

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13283